# How to access value from an item in ForEach list

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

How to access values from particular item on the list made with ForEach?
As you can see I was trying something like this (and many other options):

Text(item[2].onOff ? "On" : "Off")

I wanted to check the value of toggle of 2nd list item (for example) and update text on the screen saying if it's on or off.

And I know that it's something to do with @Binding and I was searching examples of this and trying few things, but I cannot make it to work. Maybe it is a beginner question. I would appreciate if someone could help me.

My ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    //  @Binding var onOff : Bool
    @State private var onOff = false
    @State private var test = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {

                HStack {
                    Text("Is 2nd item on or off? ")
                    Text(onOff ? "On" : "Off")
//                  Text(item[2].onOff ? "On" : "Off")
                }

                ForEach((1...15), id: \.self) {item in
                    ListItemView()
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("List"))
        }
    }
}
```

And ListItemView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListItemView: View {

    @State private var onOff : Bool = false
    //  @Binding var onOff : Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {

            Text("99")
                .font(.title)

            Text("List item")

            Spacer()

            Toggle(isOn: self.$onOff) {
                Text("Label")
            }
            .labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The appropriate approach would be to have model as `ObservableObject` and pass it between views, so each could modify related properties, and you could use them navigating between views. (`@State` actually is designed to be view-only-thing).

Comment: Isn’t @Binding designed for this as well? I read somewhere that ObservableObject is for many views. But binding is if I want to pass values of variables between just 2 views. I will read more ObservableObject. Maybe I misunderstood something :)

Comment: @State is the binding just for one view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you would like to achieve, but I made you a working example:

```
struct ListItemView: View {

    @ObservedObject var model: ListItemModel

    var body: some View {
        HStack {

            Text("99")
                .font(.title)

            Text("List item")

            Spacer()

            Toggle(isOn: self.$model.switchedOnOff) {
                Text("Label")
            }
            .labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}

class ListItemModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var switchedOnOff: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var onOff = false
    @State private var test = false

    @State private var list = [
        (id: 0, model: ListItemModel()),
        (id: 1, model: ListItemModel()),
        (id: 2, model: ListItemModel()),
        (id: 3, model: ListItemModel()),
        (id: 4, model: ListItemModel())
    ]

    var body: some View {
                NavigationView {
                    List {

                        HStack {
                            Text("Is 2nd item on or off? ")
                            Text(onOff ? "On" : "Off")
        //                  Text(item[2].onOff ? "On" : "Off")
                        }

                        ForEach(self.list, id: \.id) {item in
                            ListItemView(model: item.model)
                        }

                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("List"))
                }.onReceive(self.list[1].model.$switchedOnOff, perform: { switchedOnOff_second_item in
                    self.onOff = switchedOnOff_second_item
                })
    }
}
```

The `@Published` basically creates a `Publisher`, which the UI can listen to per `onReceive()`.

Play around with this and you will figure out what these things do!

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks @krjw, it works. I see that you created an array. I think this is good solution for final product, where I assume I would build an array from CoreData for example. But... For a purpose of building a fast prototype, is the here a way of achieving similar effect using `ForEach((1...15), id: \.self) {item in`? How would I access particular value using id? I was trying something like `Text(self.item[2].$onOff ? "On" : "Off")` but failed completely

Comment: I don’t think it is possible to do it since you need the objects available in ContentView. You cannot access it except you create a binding to every child.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I don't know how to use binding with all the rows using ForEach((1...15). You can see my example below. Thanks for your feedback. I am learning a lot. Maybe my attempts are a dead end, but at least I will learn how not to do it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

        @State private var onOffList = Array(repeating: true, count: 15)

        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                List {

                    HStack {
                        Text("Is 2nd item on or off? ")
                        Text(onOffList[1] ? "On" : "Off")
                    }
                    ForEach((onOffList.indices), id: \.self) {idx in
                        ListItemView(onOff: self.$onOffList[idx])
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("List"))
            }
        }
    }

    struct ListItemView: View {

        @Binding var onOff : Bool

        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Text("99")
                    .font(.title)
                Text("List item")
                Spacer()
                Toggle(isOn: $onOff) {
                    Text("Label")
                }
                .labelsHidden()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are directing me to use ObservableObject. And probably it's the best way to go with final product. But I am still thinking about @Binding as I just need to pass values better between 2 views only. Maybe I still don't understand binding, but I came to this solution.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    //  @Binding var onOff : Bool
    @State private var onOff = false
//  @State private var test = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {

                HStack {
                    Text("Is 2nd item on or off? ")
                    Text(onOff ? "On" : "Off")
//                  Text(self.item[2].$onOff ? "On" : "Off")
//                  Text(item[2].onOff ? "On" : "Off")
                }

                ForEach((1...15), id: \.self) {item in
                    ListItemView(onOff: self.$onOff)
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("List"))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

and ListItemView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListItemView: View {

//  @State private var onOff : Bool = false
    @Binding var onOff : Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {

            Text("99")
                .font(.title)

            Text("List item")

            Spacer()

            Toggle(isOn: self.$onOff) {
                Text("Label")
            }
            .labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}
```

What is happening now is text is being updated after I tap toggle. But I have 2 problems:

- tapping 1 toggle changes all of them. I think it's because of this line:

  ListItemView(onOff: self.$onOff)
- I still cannot access value of just one row. In my understanding ForEach((1...15), id: .self) make each row have their own id, but I don't know how to access it later on.

Comment: Thats why I save the id in an array with a model that holds the variable of the switch. You can also move the `HStack` into the `ForEach` loop and have a variable per id